# PhpStorm debugging - can i distinguish not executed part of if statement?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

For given code:

```
if(false){
something_not_executed();
}else{
something_executed();
}
```

Can PhpStorm somehow distinguish (style differently) part of code that was not executed, after debugger stepped over it?

Comment: Just do a step by step, then you will know where it didn't enter.

Comment: Nope -- debugger does not provide such info (in real time). But .. you can enable profiler (xdebug one) and see what exactly was called after the run. Alternatively just step into into each function (manually .. or just place breakpoints in each function then debugger will stop there).

Comment: Profiling manual: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Profiling+the+Performance+of+PHP+Applications

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options:

1) write a proper test using [phpunit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/index.html) for your code, and run it with code coverage

2) set a break point inside either side of the `if` statement, then you'll know which side is running because it'll stop at that point.